# Gracefully stopping mclapply cluster upon manual interrupt in RStudio?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rstudio, mclapply

I am using the `pblapply` function with the `cl` argument set to an integer instead of a cluster object. This results in `pblapply` calling `mclapply` instead of `parLapply`. There's no need to worry about entering the correct objects into the `clusterExport` function this way, which I find improves my overall workflow. However, if I need to manually interrupt the call to `pblapply` within RStudio (clicking the stop sign), the session hangs, and I end up with a bunch of runaway cores that need to be manually killed via terminal.

Note, this issue is specific to RStudio; running the same code from the terminal using `Rscript` and manually interrupting via `CTRL-C` will successfully stop the cluster. Is there a more graceful and efficient way to handle this issue when confined to RStudio?

Here's an example of my solution when working with `parLapply`. Can this be translated to work with `mclapply` instead?

```
tryCatch({
    cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1, "SOCK")
    clusterEvalQ(cl, {
        library(...) # load necessary libraries to each socket
    }
    clusterExport(cl, list=c("some_function", "some_list"))
    parLapply(cl, some_list, function(x) some_function(x))
    stopCluster(cl)
}, error=function(e) {
    stopCluster(cl)
    return(e)
}, finally = {
    try(stopCluster(cl), silent = T)
})
```

Here's an example using `pblapply`/`mclapply` without any exception handling.

```
pblapply(cl = detectCores()-1, some_list, function(x) some_function(x))
```